# Sorting Map keys by the smallest value from a list of integers

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, java-stream

I'm  trying to sort a `HashMap` as below

```
HashMap<String, List<obj> a = new hashmap<>();

a.put('a',{8,10,9});
a.put('b',{6,9,1});
```

sorting output be like

```
{ ('b',{1,6,9}) , ('a',{8,9,10}) }
```

Sorting condition:

1. Sort the values in each key
2. Sort the key based on the smallest value.

Answer (score 5):

To sort the Keys alphabetically and the values in ascending order you can do the following :

Create the map as follows:

```
SortedMap<String, List<Integer>> a = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

(*i.e.,* using [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)) to get the keys sorted in descending order, and use [Collection.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) to sort the values separately.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortedMap<String, List<Integer>> a = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(List.of(8, 10, 9));
    List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>(List.of(6, 9, 1));
    a.put("a", x);
    a.put("b", y);
    a.forEach((k, v) -> Collections.sort(v));
    a.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " - "+ v ));
}
```

Output:

```
b - [1, 6, 9]
a - [8, 9, 10]
```

---

To sort the keys by the smallest value then one can create a method to sort the `Map` as follows:

```
public static Map<String, List<Integer>> sortByMinimalValue(Map<String, List<Integer>> m){
    List<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>> list = new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet());
    m.forEach((k, v) -> Collections.sort(v));
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Collections.min(o.getValue())));
    Map<String, List<Integer>> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    list.forEach(aa -> sortedMap.put(aa.getKey(), aa.getValue()));
    return sortedMap;
}
```

**Full Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(List.of(8, 10, 9));
    List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>(List.of(6, 9, 1));
    List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 5, 7));
    Map<String, List<Integer>> a = Map.of("a", x, "b", y, "c", z);
    sortByMinimalValue(a).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " - "+ v ));
}
```

**Output:**

```
b - [1, 6, 9]
c - [2, 5, 7]
a - [8, 9, 10]
```